# getting Environment hub id in salesforce

Tags: environment-hub

how to get Environment hub org id in salesforce using soql and its use to prevent some information to be copied from production to sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a field for that on the `Organization` object or the `UserInfo` class.

You can detect if you are in a sandbox or not using:

```
Boolean isSandbox = [select IsSandbox from Organization limit 1].IsSandbox;
```

Comment: there is a field Environment hub org id in my sandbox on company information page,but unable to soql it

Comment: @ramesh Yeah I've seen that field in the UI too. Perhaps you can add explanation to your question of _exactly_ why you need it versus using other mechanisms.

Comment: This id is common in sandboxes and production.So need it to prevent some information to be copied from production to sandbox.

Comment: just tell me , how can i get it?

Comment: @ramesh If I knew I would include that in the answer...